# Take input until the end of file in python

Tags: python, eof

In ANSI C language I can take input until the EOF in the following way,

```
    while( scanf("%d",&number)!=EOF ) { //do something }
```

I have searched for the way to perform it in python. All I got was this.

```
    while True:
        try:
        s=input()
        print("Do something")
    except EOFERROR:
    break
```

When I execute in python I get to put an input and it prints "Do something". But I don't know the way to stop the input taking as it does in C when I press Ctrl+Z. Here It doesn't work, it keeps taking inputs. If there is a way to do it in python pressing Ctrl+Z or there is some other method to put an end, please let me know.

Comment: It is `EOFError`.

Comment: And in Linux you usually terminate a stream with Ctrl+D.

Comment: EOF = End Of File (not Function) 

Comment: See also [Control - Z In Python Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35644414)

Comment: @AdrianW that was helpful.

Comment: @LakshayGarg was used to hear it. Corrected! Thanks.

Comment: Reading a file like that in C is questionable. It only works if the file is guaranteed to only consist of things looking like numbers and whitespace. Otherwise you have an endless loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in windows Ctrl+D worked just fine.

Comment: @RajatRaja Is Terry Reedy's answer that Adrian W linked to what you needed here, or do you need an answer that covers Unix ^D instead of Windows ^Z here?

Comment: @abarnert well, that pretty much solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have some simple syntactic/spelling  issues:

```
while True:
        try:
            s=input()
            print("Do something")
        except EOFError:
            break
```

On Unix systems usually Ctrl+D is how you simulate an EOF from terminal

Comment: The `s=input()` and `print(...)` lines need to be indented another level.

Comment: @jwodder oops--fixed

Comment: Yeah, it worked! EOFError and Ctrl+D solved it nicely. Thanks, it was a relief.